# reactJS doesn't render the data after being fetched in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

I have an API using axios which will fetch a list of products. I have called it inside `useEffect()` hook with `[]` as the second argument. I check the data before running into `return` command of the functional component and the data is there, but my `ProductCard` component are not rendered. Could you please help me with this?

FeaturedProducts.js

```
const FeaturedProducts = (props) => {
    const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
    // const productList = useSelector(productListSelector);

    useEffect(async () => {
        let rs = await fetchFeaturedProducts();
        setProductList(rs);
    }, []);

    console.log(productList);

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid pt-5">
            <div className="text-center mb-4">
                <h2 className="section-title px-5"><span className="px-2">Featured</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div className="row px-xl-5 pb-3">
                {
                    productList.map(product => {
                        <ProductCard id={product.id} name={product.name} price={product.price} img="abc"/> // need img={product.img}
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FeaturedProducts;
```

fetchFeaturedProducts()

```
const fetchFeaturedProducts = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await AxiosClient.post("/product/search", {
            searchType: "desc",
            searchBy: "average_rating"
        });
        let data = response.data.data;

        return data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        raiseErrorMessages(error.response.data.errors);

        return [];
    }
}
```

ProductCard.js

```
const ProductCard = (props) => {
    const detailUrl = "/product?id=" + toString(props.id);

    return (
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-1">
            <div className="card product-item border-0 mb-4">
                <div className="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
                    <img className="img-fluid w-100" src={props.img} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
                    <h6 className="text-truncate mb-3">{props.name}</h6>
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <h6>{props.price}</h6>
                        {/* <h6 className="text-muted ml-2"><del>{props.price}</del></h6> */}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
                    <a href={detailUrl} className="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"><i className="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1" />View Detail</a>
                    <a href='#' className="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1" />Add To Cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductCard;
```

Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Your `.map()` callback doesn't have a return value. Use `return <ProductCard ...` or replace the curly brackets with parentheses. `product => { ... }` with `product => ( ... )`

Comment: Thank you very much. I really don't know what to say about this. Took me more than an hour before posting a question here .

Comment: Note that React expects you to pass a function to `useState` with no return value (`undefined`) or returning a clean-up function. You currently pass an async arrow function. All async functions always return a promise, which is not what React is expecting. This could become an issue when unmounting the component. To resolve this make sure you pass a normal (arrow) function, not an async function. Here are some examples: https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/04c78d38acb0e6c18dec057ea1f77bff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happens because you missed a `return` when you mapped your data

```
// .....
{
productList.map(product => {
 return (<ProductCard id={product.id} name={product.name} 
          price={product.price} img="abc"/>) // need img= 
          {product.img}
         })
}
```

or you can use `()`

```
{
productList.map(product => (
 <ProductCard id={product.id} name={product.name} 
          price={product.price} img="abc"/>) // need img= 
          {product.img})        
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. What a silly mistake. I have been asking myself how this could happen for more than an hour before posting a question here .

Comment: it is a programmers life bro 